# Trigger event for new file in Netsuite File Cabinet

Tags: events, triggers, netsuite, suitescript

I'm new to SuiteScript. Is it possible for SuiteScript 2.0 to create a trigger to start some funcionality as soon as a new file is uploaded to a particular folder in Netsuite's File Cabinet (by web services or manually by drag and drop zone)?

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see that a server side User Event script can fire for the File object like it can for so many other objects. It is not listed in the "Applies To" field for a script's Deployment record.

Additionally, Workflows have a similar field called "Record Type", and it is not listed there, either.

If you are creating File objects via SuiteTalk, you can execute logic after the "add" method is executed synchronously, or you can call a RESTLet if you would like to execute logic server-side in NetSuite.